# jQuery problem in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, coding-style

My simple jQuery script doesn't work in IE.

Please help.

the whole HTML code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        var cvalue = $(".space").css("backgroundColor");
        $(".space").css("color",cvalue);    
   });
</script>

<style>
table.tdata td {
    padding: 10px;
}
tr.zrow1 {
    background-color: #ccc
}
tr.zrow2 {
    background-color: #aaa
}
tr.zrow1 td, tr.zrow2 td {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table.tdata tr.thead1 {
    text-align: center;
}

table.tdata tr.thead {
    background-color: #003;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.thrColFixHdr #header h1 {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 10px 0; 
}
.thrColFixHdr #mainContent {
    margin: 0 200px; 
    padding: 0 10px; 
}
</style>

<div id="areaRec">
<h2 style="margin-top: 0pt;">Sample text</h2>
<p>Sample text  Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text<span class="space">_</span>text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text<br />text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text</p>
<h3 style="margin-top: 0pt;">text Sample text Sample text </h3>
<p>Sample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample text<span class="space">_</span>Sample textSample textSample textSample textSample text<span class="space">_</span>Sample textSample textSample text  textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample text.</p>
<h3 style="margin-top: 0pt;">Sample textSample textSample textSample text</h3>
<div class="show_job">
<table class="job-position" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">
<tbody>
<tr class="zrow2">
<td class="title-col" width="181" valign="top">Sample text</td>
<td width="457" valign="top">
<ul>
<li>text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text<span class="space">_</span>Sample text</li>
<li>text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text<span class="space">_</span>Sample text</li>
<li>text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text<span class="space">_</span>Sample text Sample text<span class="space">_</span>Sample text:</li>
</ul>
<blockquote><ol>
<li>Adobe Photoshop</li>
<li>Adobe InDesign</li>
<li>Adobe Illustrator</li>
</ol><ol> </ol></blockquote>
<blockquote><ol> </ol></blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="zrow1">
<td class="title-col" width="181" valign="top">Sample text</td>
<td width="457" valign="top">Sample text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="zrow2">
<td class="title-col" width="181" valign="top">Sample text</td>
<td width="457" valign="top">Sample text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="zrow1">
<td class="title-col" width="181" valign="top">Sample text</td>
<td width="457" valign="top">Sample text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="zrow2">
<td class="title-col" width="181" valign="top">Sample text </td>
<td width="457" valign="top">Sample text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="zrow1">
<td class="title-col" width="181" valign="top">Sample text </td>
<td width="457" valign="top">Sample text<span class="space">_</span>Sample textSample textSample textSample text<span class="space">_</span>Sample textSample textSample textSample textSample text </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

#### I think IE doesn't understand transparent value in css, any solution?

***Final solution:***

```
$('.space').each(function(index, value){
var cvalue = $(".space").css("backgroundColor");
if(cvalue == '' || cvalue == 'transparent'){
 var pcolor = ($(this).closest('div, p, tr').css('backgroundColor'));
 if (pcolor == '' || pcolor == 'transparent'){
  //this means the closet tag hasnt any bgcolor and it is white 
      $(this).css('color','white');
 }else {
  $(this).css('color',pcolor);
 }
}else{
 $(this).css('color',cvalue);
}
});
```

Comment: could you also show us your related html? I mean regarding .space

Comment: so why it is ok in all standard browsers such as ff, safari, opera and chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a semi colon at the end of your code
Add that and it should be okay - http://jsbin.com/anuric/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() { var cvalue = $(".space").css("background-color"); alert(cvalue); $(".space").css("color",cvalue); });
```

update;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cvalue = $(".space").css("background-color");
        alert(cvalue);
        $(".space").css("color",cvalue);    
    });
</script>
```

**Update, with your HTML;**
http://jsbin.com/asigah/

**Update2** - Ensure you have a CSS value for .space background-color in your CSS, cvalue can't find a background-color for .space if it doesn't exist.

```
.space { background-color: #fff; }
```

**Update 3** -
If you simply want to "hide" the contents of .space and just have an empty space there then use this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.space').replaceWith('&nbsp;'); 
});
```

Working sample here;
http://jsbin.com/asigah/3

**Update 4;**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.space').each(function(index, value){
    var cvalue = ($(this).closest('div, p, tr').css('background-color'));
    //alert(cvalue);
    $(this).css('color',cvalue);
  });
});
```

This will find the closest element( div, p or tr) tags and set the color of `.space` to be the same as the background color of the element it finds.
I think this is what you want.

Preview here - http://jsbin.com/asigah/28

Comment: I did what you said, but no change!

Comment: You need to specify the background-color for .space in the CSS, it can't select that if it doesn't exist. I've updated my answer

Comment: the problem exactly is here!! .space had not specific background color. I just want use the inheritance feature. I mean if it hadn't his style get his parent style.

Comment: If you don't specify the background color, it picks up the background color as transparent, which still does the job?

Comment: I tested background-color: transparent and no result again.

Comment: The jQuery is trying to find a background-specified for .space, which if it isn't set it cannot do.
Therefore it defaults to transparent, because it has nothing to find.
If you want the script specifically to use the background-color for .space and IF that doesn't exist then use the parent background-color, that's possible too.
Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: the main purpose is not to showing the value of .space class I mean '_', there is no way to use visibility: hidden or display: none! I want exactly the transparency feature. sometimes parent and the .space have the same bgcolor, that's ok but what should I do when they have different? this is a question. hope to make it clear. by the way thanks christhrower for your reply man.

Comment: If you just want to "hide" the value of .space, then you can change the jQuery for that - I've updated my answer (See update 3)

Comment: thanks, I saw that, but it is not a good idea, anyhow I want use '_'. this character will act like Zero-width non-joiner value.

Comment: because you replace '_' with space and this is not the thing i want. as i said before .space value should remain in the page but the color should be transparent(having its background color as a color, that was my idea)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help dude. I finally solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

***This code will work if you add background color to*** `.space` ***using*** `css`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var cvalue = $(".space").css("backgroundColor");
     $(".space").css("color",cvalue);    
});
```

**NOTE:**

The code works. but it added a `transparent` color to the `.space` bacause `.space` has no background defined in `css`. So you need to added `backgound` color to the `.space`.

***This code is for your current HTML and CSS structure without no change:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.space').each(function(index, value){
      var cvalue = $(this).parents().find('tr').css('backgroundColor');
      $(this).css('color', cvalue);
    });
});
```

***I have added another code snippet:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.space').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = this;
        $(this).parents().each(function() {
            var cvalue = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
            if (cvalue != '' && cvalue != 'transparent') {
                $(that).css('color', cvalue);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know really what happened, it doesn't work in my IE at all.

Comment: @Matt Ston I dont see any background color in your css for `.space`. what color do u want to add to it. background `grey` color or something else

Comment: thanks dear abdullah, but I cant set a specific style to .space :(

Comment: if you dont want to set any specific style to the `.space`, then use the second code snippet. In the second code it takes `background-color` from its parents `tr`, to which you assign `background-color` and that color is assigned to `.space`. I think you want something this.

Comment: this script will add to all my pages, I have not the same tr in all pages, this is just one of them, what is the solution for this condition? I really confused, because this script works ok in ff, only  IE socks :((